# Any good implementations of a multimap in C?

Tags: c, multimap

I'm trying to port some Delphi code to a C library, but the central structure of it is based around a multimap.  With no Generics of any kind and no language-level support for dynamic arrays, it would be pretty painful to build my own multimap in C.  But I figure someone's already written some somewhere.  Where would I find a good multimap implementation for C?

(Also, just to clarify, the "multimap" tag notes on here says "a structure similar to a map but allowing duplicate keys."  I'm a bit confused by that, because that's not the multimap container I'm familiar with.  What I need is "a structure similar to a map, but allowing multiple values for each (unique) key."  In other words, `multimap<x, y> = map<x, list<y>>`.)

Comment: Core Foundation/CFLite maybe? `CFDictionary` of `CFArray`s?

Comment: @H2CO3 I highly doubt he's going to be using the CoreFoundation libraries if he's not on mac, and considering embarcadero delphi is Windows-only, that's not an option.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII CFLite is not OS X-only, is it?

Comment: @H2CO3 no, but Windows isn't the most likely place to have that found.  I'm not saying it wouldn't work - I'm just saying it may not be the best option for his platform.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the broken tag description.

Comment: You should probably add your definition to the tag wiki - the one given is the one seen in things such as the boost::multimap library, and I suspect a lot of people are unaware of the use you are familiar with.

Comment: @Michael: Now that I think about it a little, it seems to me that the two concepts are conceptually interchangeable.  The difference is mostly in how you think about it.

Comment: @Richard: Actually, Delphi has a Mac OSX compiler now, and they've got iOS and Android compilers currently in development.  But yes, I'm looking for a solution that's not tied to Apple's libraries.

Comment: @MasonWheeler they don't, however, have an IDE for mac, meaning you must do all of your development on windows.

Comment: @Richard: Yes, that much is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although not directly a multimap library, [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html) implements a simple associative array in C and is only a header file, so it is fairly portable with low environment overhead.

Using uthash, you could simply create a multi-level associative array, treating the child associative arrays as sets. The uthash documentation provides a [simple example](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#multilevel) for creating and using multi-level associative arrays.